# Uvicorn can't find celery

Tags: python, celery, fastapi, uvicorn

I have pretty dummy code

main.py

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from tasks import hello


app = FastAPI()


@app.get('/')
def funct():
    hello.delay()
```

tasks.py

```
import time
from celery import Celery

celery = Celery(__name__, broker='amqp://guest@localhost:5672//')


@celery.task(name="hello")
def hello():
    print('hello')
    time.sleep(60*2)
    return 'Task has been completed'
```

Project tree

.

├── main.py

├── poetry.lock

├── _*pycache*_

├── pyproject.toml

└── tasks.py

Dependencies tree

```
├── billiard >=4.1.0,<5.0
├── click >=8.1.2,<9.0
│   └── colorama * 
├── click-didyoumean >=0.3.0
│   └── click >=7 
│       └── colorama * 
├── click-plugins >=1.1.1
│   └── click >=4.0 
│       └── colorama * 
├── click-repl >=0.2.0
│   ├── click >=7.0 
│   │   └── colorama * 
│   └── prompt-toolkit >=3.0.36 
│       └── wcwidth * 
├── kombu >=5.3.1,<6.0
│   ├── amqp >=5.1.1,<6.0.0 
│   │   └── vine >=5.0.0 
│   └── vine * (circular dependency aborted here)
├── python-dateutil >=2.8.2
│   └── six >=1.5 
├── tzdata >=2022.7
└── vine >=5.0.0,<6.0
fastapi 0.98.0 FastAPI framework, high performance, easy to learn, fast to code, ready for production
├── pydantic >=1.7.4,<1.8 || >1.8,<1.8.1 || >1.8.1,<2.0.0
│   └── typing-extensions >=4.2.0 
└── starlette >=0.27.0,<0.28.0
    └── anyio >=3.4.0,<5 
        ├── exceptiongroup * 
        ├── idna >=2.8 
        └── sniffio >=1.1
```

pyproject.toml

`[tool.poetry.dependencies]`
`python = "^3.10"`
`fastapi = "^0.98.0"`
`celery = "^5.3.1"`

When I trying to run server by
uvicorn main:app
I get an error:
from celery import Celery
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'celery'

I've tried to find answer in celery docs, fastapi docs, different videos, examples, articles and questions here

Answer (score 0):

Well I took packages version from some tutorial example, update env and now all is working properly.
If somebody got same issue try this one:

```
fastapi = "^0.73.0"
celery = "^5.2.3"
uvicorn = "^0.17.4"
```